# Is it possible to make theme default.xml file store specific?

Tags: magento2.2

This is my code for adding top header links in magento 2.2.2 but as i am having multiple store's it is showing in all web site's top header but my requirement is to add this link in my default store top header...not in all the multi-store web-site's header

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="wholesale">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">New Link</argument>
      <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">New Link</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```